# Label centroids in QGIS are wrong?

Tags: qgis

**Update**

> Looks like it's not solely the labeling engine but something in the 
>   projection/reprojection, on-the-fly projection, GeoPackage or some combination that's the problem - see comment below.

The centroids produced by the labeling engine in QGIS 2.18.13 do not match up with centroids produced by the Vector-Geometry Tools-Polygon Centroids. It looks like it is using a very simple centroid algorithm, not looking at the shape but the bounding box? This leads to labels being way off from the center of the polygon. Any ideas? Is there some other setting I am missing? Nothing else is labeled. Yes, I can simply label the point output shapefile from the centroid tool, but this is not ideal. Asking here before I report this as a bug.

[image]

Comment: Labeling is not so simple. What you suggest has been corrected as a bug earlier https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/1238. I suggest to write to QGIS-users mailing list and discuss about different approaches for labeling polygons.

Comment: It looks like you have the text LEFT formatted, not CENTER - is that right?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot without the choropleth map below only showing the main polygon outlines in question?

Comment: Not sure about 'LEFT' or 'CENTER' as those choices do not change the placement at all. In the new image I am using visible polygon, so disregard any that are not fully in the screen. Scioto County and Vinton County are so far off I don't even know what to think or how to start debugging this.

Comment: So, not sure how or what happened here, but downloading a fresh TIGER county dataset fixed the problem. The counties pictured above were reprojected in QGIS and stored in a GeoPackage. This might be why the centroids are off? Looks like its not the labeling engine but something in the projection/reprojection, on-the-fly projection or GeoPackage that's the problem. No time to debug on my own but I'll leave this question here in case someone else has the same issue.